# Read a CSV file line-by-line using node.js and ES6/ES7 features

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

Reading a CSV file line-by-line (i.e. without loading the whole file into memory) in Python is simple:

```python
import csv
for row in csv.reader(open("file.csv")):
    print(row[0])
```

Doing the same with node.js involves using something like [node-csv](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv), streams and callbacks.

Is it possible to use new ES6/ES7 features like iterators, generators, promises and async functions to iterate over lines of a CSV file in a way that looks more like the Python code?

Ideally I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
for (const row of csvOpen('file.csv')) {
  console.log(row[0]);
}
```

(again, without loading the whole file into memory at once.)

Comment: take a look at http://papaparse.com/

Comment: PapaParse uses callbacks, which this question is trying to avoid.

Comment: FYI, ES7 only introduces `Array#includes` and the exponentiation operator. Neither of those will help here. Async functions are a proposal. Even with async functions you will need a callback at the top level.

Comment: why not write a function `csvOpen` that internally calls node-csv and does things in the way you like? or that your question?

Comment: @FelixKling: yes, I'm assuming async functions will make it into ES7. I'd be very interested in seeing what that code with the callback at the top level might look like.

Comment: @Iceman: If you can write a `csvOpen` function that works with the for loop at the bottom of my question, I'd love to see it!

Comment: ES7 is already released. It does not contain async functions: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/ . Async functions return a promise p, so at the top level you have `asyncFunc.then(result => ...)`.

Comment: Reviewing the list of TC39 proposals, it looks like I'm asking for [Asynchronous Iterators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration#the-async-iteration-statement), which are currently at stage 2. Their example is very similar to the one in my question. Fingers crossed!

Comment: @danvk have a look at my answer. It's sloppy but does it get the job done within your guidllines: for..of loop and stream based (so no memory overload)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with node-csv, but it sounds like an iterator using a generator should do it. Just wrap that around any asynchronous callback API:

```
let dummyReader = {
  testFile: ["row1", "row2", "row3"],
  read: function(cb) {
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => cb(this.testFile.shift())).catch(failed);
  },
  end: function() {
    return !this.testFile.length;
  }
}

let csvOpen = url => {
  let iter = {};
  iter[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    while (!dummyReader.end()) {
      yield new Promise(resolve => dummyReader.read(resolve));
    }
  }
  return iter;
};

async function test() {
  // The line you wanted:
  for (let row of csvOpen('file.csv')) {
    console.log(await row);
  }
}

test(); // row1, row2, row3

var failed = e => console.log(e.name +": "+ e.message);
```

Note that `row` here is a promise, but close enough.

Paste it in [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=stage-0).