# Reading a local .csv file from react line by line

Tags: reactjs

I have a file on the **local** machine that I would like to read. I am using `create-react-app` to create my `react` application.

```
const csv =require('/path/to/csv')
```

The file is basically a `.csv` like this:

```
IBM, .025
GE, .33
etc
```

I would like to read this file, **line by line**. I can't figure out how to do it. The file needs to be parsed before anything else gets called in an application that looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const csv =require('/path/to/csv');

const App = React.createClass({
   // I would like to have the file read before stuff in here gets called
});

const appRoot = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(appRoot);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, appRoot);
```

Comment: If you're using webpack, this loader https://github.com/theplatapi/csv-loader might help

Comment: Can't get the readTextFile to work. I can type the path into the browser and I see the contents of the text file. But programatically I can't get it to work. Using Chrome.

Comment: I get file:///D:/Documents/js/table-example1/src/optimal.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: I gave up. Since I control the writing of the file, I am going to use json which seems to be supported out of the box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a CSV file line-by-line using node.js and ES6/ES7 features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313873/read-a-csv-file-line-by-line-using-node-js-and-es6-es7-features)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but I have similarly had to deal with this issue.  I found that, after requiring the package and rendering it within a hidden element, I was able to access it...

HTML:

```
<div id="hidden-element-id"></div>
```

ReactJS:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(require('yourfile'), document.getElementByID('hidden-element-id'));
```

JavaScript:

```
var sourcefile = $('#hidden-element-id').html();
```